# Knockout.js dropdown selection change event for computed observables

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to get the selection change event of dropdownlist to trigger but somehow the event is not getting fired.

Here is my code :

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice"></select>

var viewModel = function(){    
 var self= this;
self.test = ko.observable('a'),
    self.choices= ["one", "two", "three"],
self.selectedChoice = ko.computed(function () {
    var tempreview = self.test();
    if (tempreview === "a") {
        return "two";
    }
    else
        return "three";

}),
self.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   alert("the new value is " + newValue); 
})
};

 var vm =new viewModel();

 ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here is the  link : http://www.jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/73Q79/1/

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

value binding is wrong it should be some observable value. and second thing computed observable is on test property that is not changing on drop down selection so computed is not called.use test observable as value binding in dropdown.

view:-

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: test"></select>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73Q79/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without your computed by using your `self.test = ko.observable()`:

**Updated HTML:**

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: test"></select>
```

**Updated JS**

```
var viewModel = function(){    
     var self= this;
    self.test = ko.observable();
    self.choices= ["one", "two", "three"];
    self.test.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       alert("the new value is " + newValue); 
    })
};

var vm =new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73Q79/4/)**