# UI is not updated by updating observable from the custom binding method update

Tags: html, knockout.js, typescript2.0, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I'm working on a knockout application in which there is a drop-down for selecting a day of a month, it's values changes as per the month selection (ex: May- 1 to 31, Nov- 1 to 30), I successfully rendered UI, but my problem is the selected value (`this.dayValue`) is not showing as updated on UI when I tried to update from the update of the knockout binding handler. I've given the sample code below, please let me know. I guess it is a problem of rebinding even though I'm not sure. please help. Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <select data-bind="options: months, value: monthValue, event:{change: $data.noOfDays}></select>
    **<select data-bind="options: days, value: dayValue, event:{change: $data.dateModifiy}></select>**
    <select data-bind="options: years, value: yearValue, event:{change: $data.dateModifiy}></select>
</script>
```

**Typescript:**

```
export class MyView{
  private dayValue: Observable<string>;
   constructor(opt: Iclass){
     this.dayValue = opt.current().getDate().toString();
  }
  private noOfDays(): void {
    let temp: string[] = [];
    let month: number = this.months().indexOf(this.monthValue());
    let noOfDays: number = new Date(this.yearValue(), month + 1, 0).getDate();
    for (let i: number = 1; i <= noOfDays; i++) {
      temp.push(i.toString());
    }
    this.days(temp);
  }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.MyDate = {
    init(element: HTMLElement, valueAccessor: any, allBindingsAccessor: any, viewModel: any, bindingContext: any): any {
    let options: Iclass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
    let myView: Myview = new MyView(options);

    ko.cleanNode(element);
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
        template: {
            name: "person-template",
            data: myView
        }
    });

    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
},

update(element: HTMLElement, valueAccessor: any, allBindingsAccessor: any, viewModel: any, bindingContext: any): any {
    let options: Iclass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
    let myView: Myview = new MyView(options);
}
```

**Sample Code:**

```
<div data-bind="MyDate:{ name: 'sample', current: newDate}"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps this question helps you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503064/knockout-js-dropdown-selection-change-event-for-computed-observables/22503547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. However, I guess you're trying to achieve that whenever the selected month changes, the array of selectable days gets updated.

While I don't exactly see your concrete issue, I see kind of a *design issue*, which may be the root cause of having issues.

In my opinion, such a logic should be implemented at the viewmodel level (in your case your `MyView` class), as it's not related to the *view*, but purely to the *model*. In other words, to handle changes of an observable data, you should not wire it through the *view* using things like `change` events, but directly handle the observable's notifications.

I would implement something like this in the `MyView` constructor.

```
export class MyView{
  private dayValue: Observable<string>;

  constructor(opt: Iclass) {
     this.dayValue = opt.current().getDate().toString();

     // this will create an on-the-fly computed, which will gather all the observables you read inside, and run whenever each changes (like the selected month)
     ko.computed(() => {
       // something like updateSelectableDays() would be a better name
       this.noOfDays();
     });
  }
}
```

This way you can omit all the `change` events, and pass the state maintenance responsibility to the *viewmodel*. Note, that basically this is a key point of the so-called MVVM pattern.

Hope this helps, and solves your issues.